# about AlertDialog show

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to the AlertDialog show in the bottom of screen, but hava a space between AlertDialog's bottom and screen's bottom.
My code is like below :

```
private void editor(Context context){
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);    
   View view = addLayout(R.layout.edit_layout); 
   final AlertDialog myDialog = builder.create();
   Window window = myDialog.getWindow();
   myDialog.setView(view);
   myDialog.show();
   window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);// set the AlertDialog in screen the bottom.
}
```

So how the AlertDialog can be shown at the bottom of screen without the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code hope it will helps.

```
       AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
       dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

         wmlp.gravity = Gravity.Bottom | Gravity.LEFT;
        wmlp.x = 100;   //x position
        wmlp.y = 100;   //y position

         dialog.show();
```

Comment: in your way, the AlertDialog can move any place in the screen. but still have space between AlertDialog's bottom and screen's bottom.

Comment: in your way, the AlertDialog can move any place in the screen. but still have little space between AlertDialog's bottom and screen's bottom. I guess the space is in AlertDialog(maybe widget is padding the AlertDialog's bottom 10dp).so engender we can see the little space, but the true is AlertDialog is in the bottom of screen. i think you code is right.thanks you help!

Comment: i think you should check your parent layout specification.

Comment: can you send you email Address to me , I send the code to you.

Comment: my e-mail: a349770253@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
private void editor(Context context, int theme, int customLayout) {
    Dialog builder = new Dialog(context, theme);//R.style.customDialog
    builder.setContentView(customLayout);
    builder.show()
}
```

in file

> res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="customDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>


</resources>
```

in your layout set main layout gravity to:

> android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"

---

For making spacing of this customDialog style, put i.e `android:padding` to 10dp

ps. didn't test but it should be working, ping me in any problem